# QUnit - equal vs assert.equal?

Tags: javascript, qunit

I know that it is possible to write something like this

```
QUnit.test( "hello test", function( assert ) {
  assert.ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
});
```

as it is mentioned in QUnit documentation.

However, there is also a possibility to do that

```
QUnit.test( "hello test", function() {
  ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
});
```

The problem for me in the second version is that this `ok` method is not resolved and I cannot go to the implementation, however, the problem what I see in the first case is that I need to pass this `assert` to the `verificationMethod` if I have one and this feels weird.

So, ***which way is better and why?***

Comment: are you sure that the second assertion works?

Comment: well, at least for me it works. Don't really see specific requirements that my file includes to make it to work. For you it doesn't work?

Comment: I always used the first assertion. I'm a bit puzzled with the second because the absence of the parameter.

Comment: yes, I get it, but if you have a big test and you have several methods for verification, then you need to pass this as a parameter all the time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in the day we (the JS community) had no problem with defining a bunch of global functions (like `ok()` in your example). But as we've grown we've realized that this pollution of the global namespace (`window`) is a bad idea. That's what you have in the second example in your original post.

When JavaScript can't find a variable (including functions) in the local scope, it begins to look outward along the scope chain. Eventually the JS engine will come to the `window` object - our global context in browser JavaScript. If the engine still doesn't find the variable then we get a `ReferenceError`. In your case, the `ok` function is created *on the `window` object*. You can confirm this by checking that `window.ok === ok`.

But as I said, we, as a community, have moved away from global functions. A few years ago QUnit decided to provide a better interface for avoiding global functions and thus preventing potential naming collisions. This came in two forms: the `QUnit` global namespace and the `assert` argument into `test` callback functions. (We used to just write `test(function() { ... })` without the `QUnit` namespace at all.)

So... **to answer your question**... you should use the first form (`assert.ok()`) because it means you are not relying on the globally defined `ok` function to exist, which may actually collide with some other library. When QUnit executes your test functions it will provide that test function the `assert` argument which will point to the assertion library built into the QUnit framework. (Additionally, you will notice that all of the [examples on the QUnit site](http://api.qunitjs.com/ok/) use this form.)

You can [read more about this change](http://qunitjs.com/upgrade-guide-2.x/#removed-globals) in the documentation for the 2.x upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, that explains quite a lot. Now it is clear why in my project there are so many unit tests which are following the old way. Moreover, unfortunately it seems that we could not really move to the new version of qunit because we are using SAPUI5 and qunit from there.